# Pack two fractional values into a single integer while preserving a total order

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, fractions, numerical-linear-algebra, integers

Say I have points `(x, y)` and I define a total order on such point by comparing the x-values of two points and if they are equal, the y-values of two points are compared.

The `x, y` coordinates are fractional values. Assume we know the max value (e.g., all values smaller than 1000) and that there are only two digits after the decimal point.

How can I convert the point (the two fractional `x, y` coordinates) to a single integer (e.g., smaller than two billions/the int64 max value), such that the total order is preserved (the total order of comparing two pairs of coordinates.

*Example:*
A list of (x, y) cordinates such as: 
`[ (26.43, 73.11) , (326.57, 734.26), ...]` is converted to a list of (say positive) integer values and the integer value representing `(26.43, 73.11)` is still smaller than the int value representing `(326.57, 734.26)`.

I know an inefficient/insufficient way would be to use a Gödel's encoding in primes for this.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is that it is much quicker to sort a list of ints thatn it is to sort a list of floats on modern computer. It doesn't need to be exact or 100% fault tolerant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply $x$ and $y$ by $100$ you get them as ints in the range $[0,10^5-100]$.  You can then take $(100x,100y)$ to $10^5(100x)+y$ and do just what you want.  Going back to the original variables, you would have $N(x,y)=10^7x+100y$

Comment: Thank you very much. Really!